# Maximizing cross sectional area of trapezoid

Tags: algebra-precalculus, derivatives

The task is to fold a piece of sheet metal that measures 60 cm across in such a way as to form a trapezoidal "gutter" (a trough for carrying rainwater) with the maximum possible cross-sectional area. It is given that angles $A$ and $B$ are each $120^{\circ}$.

[image: Trapezoidal gutter]

My solution so far
Goal: Derive a function relating the cross-sectional area of the trapezoid to one of the dimensions of the trapezoid. Then differentiate the function to get the maximum area.

Let $DC=a$, let $AB=b$, and let $BC=c$

Because angles $A$ and $B$ are equal, the trapezoid is isosceles and so $AD = BC=c$

Drop two heights, one from $A$ and one from $B$ to opposite base $a$. This divides the trapezoid into a rectangle and two congruent right triangles. Then the area of the trapezoid is $A(b,c,h)=bh+2(\frac{1}{2}(c^2-h^2)h)=h(b+c^2-h^2)$

$2c+b=60$ (sheet metal is 60 cm across)

The right triangles are 30-60-90 triangles, therefore $h=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}c$

Substituting, $A(c)=30\sqrt{3}c-\sqrt{3}c^2+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{8}c^3$

Differentiating, $A'(c)=30\sqrt{3}-2\sqrt{3}c+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8}c^2$

Solving for the stationary point:

$30\sqrt{3}-2\sqrt{3}c+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{8}c^2=0$, which has no real solutions, and I'm stuck.

Is there something wrong with my solution? (I can't find a calculation error)

Comment: Your $A(b,c,h)$ is wrong: You need $\sqrt{c^2-h^2}$ instead of $c^2-h^2$. Always check the dimensions in geometric calculations!

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Yes, I realized this months ago. Sorry, I should have updated the question to reflect this...

Answer (score 1):

Let $l$ be the total width of the metal that's used to shape the gutter ($DA + AB + BC$), and $x$ be the base $AB$.

Then $AD = BC = (l-x)/2$.

Maybe think of the gutter as a rectangle instead.  Draw $AE$ and $BF$ so that they're perpendicular to $DC$.  Take triangle $DAE$ and pull it over so that $DA$ and $BC$ are coincident.  That makes a rectangle $ADCE$.

Now line segment $BD$ has length $\sin(\pi/3)(l-x)/2 = (l-x)/4$,

and line segment $DC$ has length $\cos(\pi/3)(l-x)/2 = \sqrt3(l-x)/4$.

Then the area is $(x + (l-x)/4)(\sqrt3(l-x)/4) = \sqrt3(3x+l)(l-x)/16$.

Taking the derivative with respect to $x$ and setting to $0$ gives $x = l/3$.

Comment: By length $l$ do you mean the dimension perpendicular to the cross-section? (if so, I don't see how the length of the gutter is relevant to maximizing the cross-sectional area.

Comment: Edited my definition of $l$.